# Apparent rotation in connection with observation of Lorentz contracted objects

Tags: special-relativity

My question is related to the so called invisibility of Lorentz contraction, but I am essentially concerned with part related to the apparent rotation often mentioned in explanation of the phenomenon.

---

Edit: I realize I made some mistakes in my calculations. I still wonder 
how is it possible to see the back side of an approaching object?

---

I will explain my own reasoning first to give you a background of how I (perhaps miss-) understand the situation.

Imagine a camera in front of a train where a picture is taking by a (thought) instantaneous shutter.  We assume that photons from the middle of the train arrive at the shutter positioned so that they arrive at the middle of the picture.

If the train is motionless in relation to the camera and placed in darkness and lit by a thought instantaneous flash, we would see only a point on the middle of train (assuming a flat train so that the middle is also closest to the shutter) if the shutter is opened just at the arrival of the light front of the reflected flash.

If the train is lit during a long enough time we would see a picture of the whole train, since e.g. some photons from the front of the train emitted somewhat earlier will pass the shutter at the same time as the photons from the part of the train which is closest to the shutter (i.e. essentially as in any normal picture).

Imagine now the same setup involving a moving train lit under a longer period of time. (Assume for later comparison that the train moves from left to right from the camera’s point of view). Assume that the shutter is opened at a point in time which would allow the middle of the train to be depicted – as before - in the picture’s middle.

For this reason we would see the middle portion of the train similar to the picture we took before of the motionless train with only minor distortions from the slight differences in the times of flight for photons emanating near the train’s center.

Let us also look at the fate of photons from the front of the train reaching the shutter at the right time to allow shutter passage.  These photons were emitted at an earlier time than the ones from the middle to reach the shutter at the right time.

For this reason we would see the front from a different perspective with the train placed at its earlier position somewhat further to the left.

If we make a special study of picture of the front we first note that - just as for the picture of the middle of the train - we would expect a small distortion around the center of the front. This distortion however would be more pronounced since the (assume at first flat) front of the train will require that photons from the far side of the front  have longer travel time and therefore were emitted earlier, and therefore contribute more to the perspective by further broadening the front in the resulting picture.  (We now note in passing that by the same type of reasoning the round front of a steam engine would broaden the picture of the front even more.)

The resulting picture where the front is fitted to the middle and other parts of the train is to give us a feeling that the front part of the train is rotated clockwise towards the camera or the person looking at the picture.

I now want you to direct your attention to the animation of the same situation where dice are coming from left to right. As you see the rotations in the animation is counterclockwise i.e. opposite my expectation.   I am thinking of the link

https://physicsworld.com/a/the-invisibility-of-length%E2%80%AFcontraction/

It is obviously different from mine.  I note that the animation is about moving dice, continuously emitting light, but I still consider the animation to be made up by single pictures such as mine, so my question is how that is possible?

I am aware that I made a classical explanation but I wouldn’t expect the Lorentz contraction (or the effect that is said to cancel its appearance)   to contribute to the sign of the rotation. How can, in the animation, the back side of the dice (the 4) emit any photons at all to reach the shutter and contribute to the picture?

Answer (score 0):

Picture of moving object depends on spatial position of a camera with respect to this object.

The reason why “moving” objects appear rotated is that the camera takes picture “from the rear”.

As a matter of fact, Terrell in his paper worked in camera’s frame; the sphere was “moving” in this frame.  If the camera was at distance $l$ when the sphere crossed point of closest approach, the picture was taken only after a time $\Delta t$ equal to $l/c$.  At that moment the sphere had already moved further away.

Due to aberration of light photons that approached camera (for example) at right angle had been emitted backward at angle $\sin \theta =v/c$ in the sphere’s frame. The shell of the sphere obscure the path of some photons, so these rays were not visible; an observer could not see its front part.

In principle, the left and right edges and the whole "upper" hemisphere (if the camera was "on the top)" can be seen, but then you need to take picture from another point.

No problems arise at all if someone wishes to take picture of an object “at rest” by means of “moving” camera.

The same picture may have twofold explanation: in the camera’s frame or in the object’s (sphere’s) frame. Analysis in sphere’s frame is a bit simpler.

In the sphere’s frame this “rotated” image can be explained that the camera took the picture of the object “from the rear”.  Instead of being “at rest” one can run himself with camera towards, over and away from the object and take a sequence of pictures from different spatial positions.

The higher camera's velocity the further the camera would move from the sphere while light from the sphere toward aperture covers distance $l$; the more the "sphere" would be "rotated".

It is convenient to consider (how a picture would appear) from different spatial positions this way:

1)  Consider that a camera was “at rest” relatively to the object;

2)  Draw paths of rays from the object towards an aperture and from the aperture towards a photo emulsion; it is “simple” picture.

3)  Imagine that aperture of moving camera coincides with aperture of “stationary” camera at the moment of the “click”; the same information goes through apertures of the both cameras at this instant.

4)  Take into consideration effects of motion of the film and Lorentz – contraction of the film;

For "rotated and undistorted" sphere motion of the film  “compressed” the image, but due to Lorentz – contraction of the film the image was be $\gamma$ times stretched back after development of the film. This way the sphere or cube appeared “undistorted”.

The ”moving” camera can also take a picture of an object when they ARE at points of closest approach. Analysis in this case is simple; rays of light from the edges towards aperture and from aperture to the film form similar triangles. Photons that have simultaneously (in sphere’s frame) been emitted from the edges of the sphere would simultaneously hit the film.  Hence, due to Lorentz – contraction of the film an image would appear $\gamma$ times stretched. Due to motion of the film the image would be shifted. “Moving” cameraman would explain that this picture was due to Lorentz contraction of his own camera and his own film. Edges of the sphere would be perfectly seen on the picture.

“Stationary” cameraman (as soon as he synchronizes clocks in his frame according to Einstein’s synchrony convention) would have corresponding explanation of the same “stretched” picture of "approaching" sphere according to his own interpretation and his own judgments about simultaneity.

It should be noted, that if the uniformly moving object permanently shines and spreads its image in all directions and if surface of the object does not change over time, one can speak about “field” of images that moves together with an object without any delays. In this light, one can say that "stretched" explanation may be as good as "rotated" one.

[This](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/312494874_THE_TERRELL-PENROSE_ROTATION_WHEN_PHOTOGRAPHING_A_SPHERE_AT_REST_WITH_A_MOVING_CAMERA) or [this](https://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1088/1742-6596/1251/1/012035)  articles give some more details and considers “relativistic” photography of the both sphere and measuring rod.

Comment: Thanks. 
I will look through your answer and the article. Let me just make my point from my edit clearer. I realize that light from the back edge of a moving dice - from the URL I posted - furthest away from the camera must have been emitter earlier to arrive at the same time as the light from the front of the dice. However, at that earlier point in time the whole cube of the dice was also in place shielding the emitted light in the direction towards the camera. 

I therefore understand that a transparent cube may show this effect but it is not clear how it would work from a normal dice.